# Spring-batch fail to build on windows 10

Tags: gradle, spring-batch, asciidoctor

i'm trying to build spring-batch from source on windows 10 with gradle.

but it fail on Task: makePDF.

the complete scan of the build is in this link below:

https://scans.gradle.com/s/sqkcmced55zao/

java: java version "1.8.0_221"
gradle version: 4.10.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are aware of that, it looks like it's an issue with `asciidoctorj-pdf:1.5.0-alpha.16`. We tried to upgrade it to the latest `1.5.0-alpha.18` but the issue still happens, we are working on it. In the meantime, you can skip the `makePDF` task or downgrade `asciidoctorj-pdf` to `1.5.0-alpha.15` (with which the build passes).